# An operator invariant under translations is a convolution with a tempered distribution.

Tags: operator-theory, schwartz-space

It is possible to extend a continuous operator defined in Schwartz space $S$ to $L^p,\ 1\leq p<\infty$?

Example: Let $T$ a bounded operator defined on $L^p,\ 1\leq p<\infty$ invariant under traslation. By a theorem, exists a tempered distribution $u$ such that $T(f)=f*u$ for all $f\in S$ (schwartz space).

Now, as $f$ is bounded (continuous) and S dense in $L^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$, then $T(f)=f*u$ for all $f\in L^p$?

Comment: In the title, you have an invariant translation operator. In the body, you have an operator invariant under translation (i.e. a translation-invariant operator). Which one is it?

Comment: under is the correct